# Автоматическая генерация свойств и методов Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Например я наследую некий интерфейс

```
public class newClass : newInterface
{
...
}
```

И мне соответственно внутри класса надо реализовать члены данного интерфейса, возможно как нибудь генерировать шаблоны для этих членов средствами Visual Studio? Или все вручную придется описывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставить курсор на newInterface, нажать Ctrl+. В выпадайке будет пункт Implement Interface.

Answer (score 1):

Ставите курсор на `newInterface`, нажимаете `Shift+Alt+F10` и выбираете одну из опций, как имплементировать интерфейс: явно или неявно (поиграетесь, разницу увидите сами).

На будущее:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Средствами Visual Studio это возможно, выше сказали, как это сделать, не буду повторяться. Добавлю еще, что  есть такое замечательное расширение, которое называется Resharper. У него огромное множество всяких полезных возможностей, в том числе и та, что вас интересует. 
Вы создаете некий класс, реализующий интерфейс, рядом с классом появляется маленькая подсказка с выпадающим списком, в одной из опций которого вам предлагается реализовать методы интерфейса. Выглядит это так:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: В Студии ж все то же самое. Подсказка, менюшка.

Comment: видимо я очень давно не пользовался студией без решарпера

Comment: Стоит попробовать :). Я без Решарпера уже года полтора сижу и скучаю только по навигации по заглавным буквам, просмотру иерархии классов и обнаружению неиспользуемых участков кода (хотя тут FxCop спасает).

Comment: честно говоря, не вижу смысла менять удобство на его отсутствие)

Comment: Мне в какой-то момент надоело, что Решарперу всегда мало ресурсов. Плюс были периодически проблемы со Студией/солюшном, где-то Решарпер гадил в системе. Поэтому я плюнул.